# How to do NAT with PHP sockets

Tags: php, sockets, udp, nat, stun

I'm trying to make a peer to peer app in php to work in the same kind of way skype works. It works with internal addresses, but when I try to send data to my external address the message never gets there. Obviously I'm missing some address translation, but I'm at a loss for how to do that with PHP sockets. Is it possible?

This is the code i have at the moment to receive the message, which I run first to wait for some message:

```
<?php
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, SOL_UDP) or die("Could not create socket: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($socket)));
socket_bind($socket, "0.0.0.0", 100) or die("Could not bind socket: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($socket)));

$ret = "";
$from_ip = "";
$from_port = 0;


echo "waiting...\n";
socket_recvfrom($socket, $ret, 6, 0, $from_ip, $from_port);

var_dump($ret, $from_ip, $from_port);

socket_close($socket);
```

And then when its waiting, I run this code to send a message:

```
<?php
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, SOL_UDP) or die("Could not create socket: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($socket)));


$to_ip = "externalip"; //works with internal "127.0.0.1";
$to_port = 100;
$message = "hello!";

socket_sendto($socket, $message, strlen($message), 0, $to_ip, $to_port);
echo "sent\n";

socket_close($socket);
```

But it sends and exits, but the first script is still waiting... 
Been at this for a while now, can anyone help me out?

-- Edit --

Ok so i've implemented a stun server and set up port forwarding for it like so:

```
<?php

echo "-- STUN SERVER --\n";

$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, SOL_UDP) or die("Could not create socket: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($socket)));
socket_bind($socket, "0.0.0.0", 5104) or die("Could not bind socket: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($socket)));


do {
    $ret = "";
    $from = "";
    $port = 0;

    echo "waiting...\n";
    socket_recvfrom($socket, $ret, 6, 0, $from, $port);

    echo "received: $ret\n";

    $message = $from.":".$port;
    socket_sendto($socket, $message, strlen($message), 0, $from, $port);
    echo "sent: $message\n\n";
}
while (true);
```

and changed my first script to get its ip/port from the stun server:

```
<?php
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, SOL_UDP) or die("Could not create socket: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($socket)));
socket_bind($socket, "0.0.0.0", 100) or die("Could not bind socket: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($socket)));

$ret = "";
$from = "";
$port = 0;


echo "sending info to stun server...\n";
$to_ip = "stunip";
$to_port = 5104;
$message = "get_ip";
socket_sendto($socket, $message, strlen($message), 0, $to_ip, $to_port);

echo "waiting for stun...\n";
$stuninfo = "";
socket_recvfrom($socket, $stuninfo, 25, 0, $from, $port);

var_dump($stuninfo); // i use this info in my second script


echo "waiting...\n";
socket_recvfrom($socket, $ret, 6, 0, $from, $port);

var_dump($ret, $from, $port);

socket_close($socket);
```

It gets the info from the stun server ok and waits for another connection, but when i use that info in my second script, the first script still doesn't receive any message.. is there another step I'm missing?

Comment: You are searching for the term `NAT traversal`. Have a look at [STUN](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_Traversal_Utilities_for_NAT)

Comment: Ahah, I think I understand. So in my first script, id first send a request to a server using my socket, which will return my public IP and port used to make that request, then I can use that IP and port in the second script? Is it really that easy, or is there another step I'm missing?

Comment: @hek2mgl I've implemented a stun server, it seems to be sending me the exactly what i was expecting, my ip address and port 100, but then when i send a message to it from my second script, the first one still never receives it :( Can you, or anyone, see what the problem might be and point me in the right direction?

Comment: Hey, I was AFK for a while. I never personally implemented STUN, unfortunately I cannot help much. I was just knowing the terms and dropped them here to point you into the right direction. Just from the first look, it seems like you are missing something.

Comment: I think i need to keep a connection open that I connect to from the other script, but how could I do that in PHP?

Comment: `$to_ip = "stunip";` – since `stunip` obviously can only be meant to be a placeholder… may I ask where you get that IP from? I’m asking because the answer to your question might well be hidden in an according clarification from your side.

Comment: have you completed this one?? i am searching this kinda stuff help me if you could... Thanks