# How to get past NAT to connect to my home devices

Tags: nat, stun

I am interested in connecting to a web server I am running inside my home network on a Raspberry Pi. I have been reading up on how STUN servers work, and gather that they determine the port that the external facing router uses to redirect HTTP requests back to a device inside the local network.

I have an external website and I put a php file there to report back on the IP and port that requests come from. I can see that the requests come from the IP of my home router and each device uses a consistent port when a request is made.

If we assume my router has an external address of 123.123.123.123 and my Pi is allocated port 50500 for return requests I thought I would therefore be able to access the website on my Pi by using these combined as http://123.123.123.123:50500. However this does not work. Should this work?

(Note: port forwarding is not an option so please do not suggest that).

Comment: It is unclear. from your question, exactly what you want to connect to what and in which way. I can make a guess, but it is better if your question is not so vague. If you want to initiate a connection, from outside your home network, to a Raspberry Pi web server behind a NAT inside your home network, then port forwarding is your only option. Why rule it out? It would be nice to know.

Comment: While I dont understand how "connecting to a web server " is unclear I am happy to explain. This means making a http call to a web server, typically over port 443 or port 80.

Comment: Port forwarding is not an option as my router does not support it and regardless I want this solution to be easy for a non-technical user. For example, I can run liblinphone as a python process and place a call to my Pi through the NAT using a SIP Phone. So why cant I just as easily connect to a website on the Pi if I know the IP and port the NAT uses to identify it.

Comment: The NAT assigns a new external port number dynamically, for each new connection with the outside world, established from a computer in its local network. When you start liblinphone it connects to a SIP proxy, telling it where it is located (IP & port), so it can route calls to it. Building a proxy like that can very complicated, it's much easier to replace your router by a better model that does support port forwarding. Such a router might also support UPnP (Universal Plug and Play). See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Plug_and_Play but that is not perfect either.

Comment: Your answer is not helpful and is simply a distraction. This is exactly why I said dont suggest port forwarding. I am designing a solution for non technical users and all hardware.

Comment: So to add to this, I just worked out that my linphone test only allows me to call the Pi for a little while, after which I can no longer connect. I am assuming this is because after a while the NAT changes the port used to identify the Pi (something I have observed with the test page on my site). This is not directly relevant to the problem, but it provides some insight into how the NAT is working.

Comment: As another update, I thought the issue might be that I had a Restricted Cone NAT, which would mean it would only accept packets from an address that it previously sent packets to (according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation). So I tried the following: 1. logged on to my server  2. from the Pi I connected to the test webpage to get the ip and port  3. I then tried to curl to a page on my Pi using the IP:port combination. The curl request simply timed out. Which leads me back to my original question of why I cannot access the Pi using the identified IP:port combination

Comment: It was not meant as a distraction, just as sound advice. You need to know a lot more about NAT to do what you want. It is, as I have indicated before, not entirely impossible. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAT_traversal The official term is; "Network address translator traversal". I hope this gets you further.

Answer (score 1):

So I think the answer here is related to the fact that only UDP and TCP traffic are simple enough to get through the NAT using just the pi and port combination. I am trying to make a HTTP request over the same channel but this is more complex and therefore doesnt make it through.

That's pretty vague, and possibly not entirely correct. So I would love to hear from any experts in the field who can add more depth to this answer or correct me.

Comment: This is quite a common problem and other approaches such as using web sockets like this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22899762/how-to-do-nat-with-php-sockets?rq=1 also remain unanswered.

Comment: Let me post another distracting comment. :-) This is, in the end, not a good question for Stack Overflow. It is a too broad. At least you're testing a lot of stuff, which is good. Now you've got to choose a method to traverse the NAT and try to implement it. When you have specific problems doing that, then post your code on SO and people might be able to help you. Usually a question without code is not answered with any great detail. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1):

The [ngrok](https://dashboard.ngrok.com/get-started) is the easy and free one.

I  setup webhook for social media in five minutes when develop IM robot .

There is a sample from [Slack](https://api.slack.com/tutorials/tunneling-with-ngrok), but it apply to any social media or could solution which need webhook.

Comment: Thanks very much. Will take a look at those. NoIp is something I was looking at also.